# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException Stack in System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AcceptCallback

Tags: c#, sockets

Please see code below, it is not very stable in my windows service, after starting for a while, it throw the error:

> Exception is as below, Pls anybody help?  Application:
>   REMSServerService.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description:
>   Unknown exception。  Info: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException Stack in
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AcceptCallback(System.Object) in
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.RegisteredWaitCallback(System.Object,
>   Boolean) 在
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.PerformWaitOrTimerCallback(Syste‌​m.Object,
>   Boolean)

The error was catched on : **readsize = listensocket2.Receive(buffer_receive);**

The project is on a data communication center, the clients are GPRS DTU socket client.

Please help!!!

Part I:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
            IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(RemsSocket.myip, RemsSocket.webport);
            Socket listensocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            listensocket.Bind(endpoint);
            listensocket.Listen(200);
            Thread th = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(RemsSocket.listen_send));
            th.IsBackground = true;
            th.Start(listensocket);
    }
```

Part II:

```
    public static void listen_send(object source)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            done.Reset();
            Socket listensocket = (Socket)source;
            listensocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(acceptcallback_send), listensocket);
            done.WaitOne();
        }
    }

    public static void acceptcallback_send(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        done.Set();
        Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket listensocket2 = socket.EndAccept(ar);
        byte[] buffer_validate = new byte[buffersize];
        string hostcode = "";
        byte[] buffer_send = Hex.HexStringToByteArray(validate_code);
        listensocket2.Send(buffer_send, 0, buffer_send.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        listensocket2.Receive(buffer_validate);
        int readsize = buffer_validate.Length; //listensocket2.EndReceive(ar);
        if (readsize > 0)
        {
            bool success = FirstValidate(buffer_validate, ref hostcode);
            bool validate = BLL.ExtHostBLL.CanCommunicate(hostcode); 
            if (success && validate)
            {
                LoopSendReceive(hostcode, listensocket2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Part III:

```
    public static void LoopSendReceive(string hostcode, Socket listensocket2)
    {
        listensocket2.Blocking = true;
        byte[] buffer_receive = new byte[buffersize];
        bool validate = BLL.ExtHostBLL.CanCommunicate(hostcode); 
        while (validate)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            int readsize;
            bool success;
            IPEndPoint clientipe = (IPEndPoint)listensocket2.RemoteEndPoint;
            byte commandByte = Hex.HexStringToByteArray(command_8);
            listensocket2.Send(commandByte, 0, commandByte.Length, SocketFlags.None);
            listensocket2.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
            int countSocketException = 0;
            readsize = listensocket2.Receive(buffer_receive);
            if (readsize != 0)
                {
                    clientipe = (IPEndPoint)listensocket2.RemoteEndPoint;
                    ClientDto client = hostList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Ip == clientipe.Address.ToString());
                    ParseChannel.AlertStatus[] data;
                    ParseChannel channel = new ParseChannel();
                    success = channel.Parse(buffer_receive, client, out data);
                    if (!success)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    SaveData(data, client);
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to know which ErrorCode is in the SocketException to really know what is happening

Comment: The last ErrorCode is Success, another is TimeOut often throw out.

Comment: Then it's really clear, the Receive function is timing out because the other side doesn't sends the data or the packet is lost (if it's GPRS then my vote goes for lost packet), if that's the case then you need a mechanism to query again for the same packet to the other side when you catch a timeout

Comment: Post the full exception ToString. You are making the common mistake of assuming that Receive will receive an entire "message". TCP is a streaming protocol.